Tautological one-form on a product manifold
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\theta$ be the tautological one-form on the cotangent bundle $X := T^*M$ of $M$. Using local coordinates $(x, \xi)$ on $X$, it takes the form $\theta = \xi_i dx^i$.
I would like to determine the tautological one-form on the product manifold $M \times \mathbb{R}$ in terms of $\theta $, the one on $M$.
It is apparently known that any smooth differential form $\omega$ of degree $p$ on $M \times \mathbb{R}$ can be written uniquely as $$ \omega = \omega_1(y) + dy \wedge \omega_2(y), $$ were $\omega_1$ is a smooth family of $p$-forms on $M$ and $\omega_2$ is a smooth family of $(p-1)$-forms on $M$. More generally on a product manifold $M \times N$ we have a bilinear map $ \Omega^i(M) \otimes \Omega^j(N) \rightarrow \Omega^{i+j}(M\times N)$ by taking the wedge product of the pullbacks of our differential forms by $p_1$ and $p_2$, which are the canonical projections $p_1 : M\times N \rightarrow M$ and $p_2 : M\times N \rightarrow N$ ; however this map is not bijective (just injective).
I would appreciate any help, thanks.

You don’t need all these generalities, as you’re looking for a $1$-form on $T^*(M\times \Bbb R)$. What additional local coordinate do you need to get from $M$ to $M\times \Bbb R$?

@TedShifrin On $M\times \mathbb{R}$ we have $(x,y)$ and on $T^*(M\times \mathbb{R})$ we have $(x,y,\xi,\eta)$ with $(\xi,\eta)$ dual coordinates of $(x,y)$. Then can we just say the tautological one-form is $\xi_i dx^i + \eta dy$ ?

Yes, and the $\eta,dy$ part is globally well-defined :)
